# Why max() function in C++ giving error "no matching function for call to max"? Same code works if I do it explicitly with conditional statement

Tags: c++, function, stack, max

Both parameters of max are of type **int**, then why am I getting this error?

> Code is to find maximum depth of paranthesis in a string

```
int maxDepth(string s) {
        stack<char> stac;
        int maxDepth = 0;
        for(auto &elem: s) {
            if(elem == '(') 
                stac.push(elem);
            else if(elem == ')')
            {
                // maxDepth = max(maxDepth, stac.size()); // this doesn't work
                if(stac.size() > maxDepth) // this works, why?
                    maxDepth = stac.size();
                stac.pop();
            }
        }
        return maxDepth;
    }
```

Comment: The arguments to `max` should have the same type . Your alternative will fail if `maxDepth < 0`

Comment: @M.M But my maxDepth is never going to be negative, right? What do you mean by alternative?

Comment: By "your alternative" I mean the code you wrote in the question to use instead of `max`

Comment: `size_t maxDepth(string s)` and `size_t maxDepth` will help you

Comment: Leads to a sidenote, you sure you want to reuse `maxDepth`? Compiler won't care, but human brains tend to break easily, and a find-and-replace could have hilarious consequences.

Comment: side note: `int` can be made negative if you overflow it with a large enough `stac.size()` And one of the points M.M is trying to make is `stac.size` doesn't return `int`.

Comment: `"Both parameters of max are of type int"` is the mistake. The error message should show you both types. `deduced conflicting types for parameter 'const _Tp' ('int' and 'std::stack<char>::size_type' {aka 'long unsigned int'})` If you turn up the warning level you'll see that your workaround is also comparing values of different types. https://godbolt.org/z/KWjG8sjjG

Comment: So, the code in the question works fine, and you want people to modify it to figure out what you're asking? Don't do that. Post the code that doesn't work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason why your compiler reject your call to the `std::max` function is because it cannot deduce the type it needs.

Below is a typical implementation of `std::max`

```
 template<typename _Tp>
    _GLIBCXX14_CONSTEXPR
    inline const _Tp&
    max(const _Tp& __a, const _Tp& __b)
    {
      // concept requirements
      __glibcxx_function_requires(_LessThanComparableConcept<_Tp>)
      //return  __a < __b ? __b : __a;
      if (__a < __b)
    return __b;
      return __a;
    }
```

Both parameters receive `_Tp` but the way that [template type deduction](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/template_argument_deduction) works is it evaluates the type for each of the template parameters and then compares if they match. Since one of your parameters is an `int` and other is a `size_t` which is an unsigned int then you will have an error.

Here's what you can do when using `std::max`:

1. Cast so the parameters match:

   ```
   maxDepth = max(static_cast<size_t>(maxDepth), stac.size());
   ```
2. Declare the type, which is also more readable:

   ```
   maxDepth = max<size_t>(maxDepth, stac.size())
   ```

Regarding your own program, I advise that you change the type of `maxDepth` to `size_t`.

Also, for readability, change the function name so it does not have the same name as the variable.